# Print PDF Letter. Image not readable or empty

Tags: pdf

When using the "Print PDF letter for Contacts" action, I tried to add an image and when I downloaded the PDF file, in place of the image, said "Image not readable or empty"

I've tried all the solutions listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558449/dompdf-image-not-readable-or-empty and nothing.

Thks

Comment: When you say "Image Tool" are you referring to CKEditor?, I'm using CKEditor for upload the image. Thks

Comment: yes, then are you uploading the image and selecting the image - from the tool

Comment: what version of Civi are you using ?? and are you using drupal ??

Comment: Please don't give your comment against Answer this will not trigger an notification for me please try to add your comment in the add a comment option - so I will get an notification - thanks

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newcomer. :-)

Comment: I'm uploading the image from CKEditor. My Drupal version is 7.41 and Civi 4.6.10

Comment: This will happen only if the image is not available - saying if your image is in your PC - so please move the image to the instance and then try uploading the image that should work

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add Image tool and upload your image using the Image tool that should work correctly - please try the same against Demo server

Answer (score 0):

There were instructions here suggesting using the image path of sites/files/etc ... and yes I mean without a leading slash

I was slightly doubtful of this but it definitely fixed the problem in our case, so using

```
<img src="sites/example.org/files/logo.png">
```

worked for us.