# Dompdf image not found or type unknown

Tags: pdf, dompdf

CiviCRM 5.45.5, Drupal 7.87.  Getting the dreaded "image not found or type unknown" error in PDFs.  I've tried the solutions listed here ([Print PDF Letter. Image not readable or empty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7366/print-pdf-letter-image-not-readable-or-empty)), to wit:

- absolute link to image
- relative link to image
- adjusted relative links such as sites/default/etc. (no leading slash) and the . in front of a leading slash
- link to image on another server/site
- reuploading the image, and converting from .png to .jpg
- confirming that dompdf remote images are enabled
- confirming that file permissions allow for reading (the images are all accessible directly via the browser)

What am I missing here?  This functionality works on every other Civi site (of comparable versions for Civi and Drupal) that I can access.

Comment: You should be able to put `global $_dompdf_show_warnings; $_dompdf_show_warnings = true;` in civicrm.settings.php to output some secondary messages to the pdf giving a more detailed message, but that causes a different crash for me. You can add `\CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message($errstr);` at https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/70910027340e9455cbc1cfc655530eb87419dd9c/src/Helpers.php#L560 and then check civi log. Also see this block for the many reasons you can get this error: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/70910027340e9455cbc1cfc655530eb87419dd9c/src/Image/Cache.php#L80-L178.

Comment: Did you try creating the full instance in a different server ? and then test it

Comment: We actually were able to debug based on Demerit's suggestion - it turned out to be an issue with the SSL certificate on the site.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue ? - else Try removing the SSL certificate and then try (I did had similar issue on the server were server PDF font was not picking correctly )

Comment: The client's web host is correcting the SSL cert issue now; we have a patch in place to get the client by temporarily.  As a side note for others reading this thread later, the same cert issue impacted templates with images that are downloaded as Word or OpenOffice files.